# Database Structuring of Data

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql, bigdata

I'm thinking of the most efficient way to store data , priority is retrieving of data fast.

I have a set of data. Let take it as for example a Pokemon Card

Imagine that in this world , each card has it own unique ID but there can be duplicate properties of each card.

I'm thinking of creating 2 table to store such data

**1st Table**

Properties of each card that exist in this world with a unique ID

**2nd table**

for each ID , it can contain multiple rows of Unique ID of all the card in the world.

In summary , i'm thinking of having 1 table to store properties , another table to store who own this card with that property.

is there any better method to store and retrieve data. Planning to use mysql. Let's just take it as there can only be at most 100 million unique cards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have cards. Cards have properties. Some cards have the same properties and I assume properties are complex entities, they have some properties too.

It would make the most sense to have 3 tables: one for cards and who owns them. One for all the unique properties and then a many-to-many table between cards and properties.

Your select queries have a double JOIN. If you add indexes to the primary keys of all the tables it should be super fast.

```
Cards
  id
  owner
  name

Properties
  id
  value
  foo
  bar

Cards2Properties
  card_id [fk]
  property_id [fk]
```

Comment: Good thing about this suggestion is that you can also add new properties without changing the model.